# Symbol equality

Tags: common-lisp, symbols

In [Paul Graham's book *ANSI Common Lisp*](http://www.paulgraham.com/acl.html), while discussing symbol vs string manipulation, he says

> Symbols can be compared in one step with `eql` ..."

(p138).  Here are two cases of symbol comparison:

```
(setq x 3)
3
(setq a 'x)
X
(setq b 'x)
X
(eq a b)
T
```

So, since `a` and `b` point to the same symbol object, named `"X"`, they are `eq`. However, this contrasts with

```
(setq a (copy-symbol 'x))
#:X
(setq b (copy-symbol 'x))
#:X
(symbol-name a)
"X"
(symbol-name b)
"X"
(eq a b)
NIL
(eql a b)
NIL
(equal a b)
NIL
(equalp a b)
NIL
```

Now, `a` and `b` point to different `symbol` objects, even though they have the same `symbol-name` and same print name. My questions are:

1. why does Graham say `eql` rather than `eq`, and
2. in the second case, why are `a` and `b` not at least `equalp`?

Comment: EQ or EQL makes no difference when comparing symbols. copy-symbol returns a fresh, uninterned symbol. Thus symbols created by copy-symbol are not eq to anything. They are always different.

Comment: @Rainer Joswig Thanks for calling my attention to the fact that `copy-symbol` does not intern the symbol. How then does one use `(copy-symbol 'x t)` to copy all the symbol features of X (except `symbol-name`) to another interned symbol Y? Or do you have to first create an interned symbol and then `setf` each feature separately?

Comment: `How then does one use (copy-symbol 'x t) to copy to copy all the symbol features of X (except symbol-name) to another interned symbol?`-> you can intern the new and copied symbol into some other package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [`eql`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_eql.htm) over [`eq`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_eq.htm)?

[`eql`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_eql.htm) is "more predictable" in the sense that it is less implementation-dependent.
E.g., non-immediate numbers (i.e.,
non-[`fixnum`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_fixnum.htm)s) can be non-[`eq`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_eq.htm)
in some implementations and [`eq`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_eq.htm) in others:

```
(= 1.5d0 1.5d0)
=> T
(eql 1.5d0 1.5d0)
=> T
(eq 1.5d0 1.5d0)
=> T in some implementations, NIL in others
```

## why aren't the identically named symbols not [`equalp`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_equalp.htm)?

That's what the spec says :-)

Note that it does violated the rule of thumb:

> A rough rule of thumb is that two objects are [`equal`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_equal.htm) if and only if their printed representations are the same.

The main non-[histerical reason](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/hysterical-reasons.html) for this is that symbol, while being
"atomic", still carries many baggage (e.g., variable and function
bindings). IOW, a [`symbol`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_symbol.htm) is
much more than its name.

Also, one generally expects that [`equal`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_equal.htm) forms evaluate to
[`equal`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_equal.htm) values, which cannot be the case if different symbols (with
possibly different bindings!) are evaluated as [`equal`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_equal.htm).

Now, the only differences between [`equal`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_equal.htm) and [`equalp`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_equalp.htm) are

1. case-insensitive character (and string) comparison
2. comparing numbers using [`=`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_eq_sle.htm)
3. recursively descending into
   [`structure`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_docume.htm),
   [`array`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_array.htm), and
   [`hash-table`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_hash_t.htm).

None of these changes affects the "similar evaluation rule" above,
so there is no reason for [`equalp`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_equalp.htm) to compare symbols based on
their names.

If you want to compare symbols by names, you can
use [`string=`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_stgeq_.htm):

```
(eq '#:a '#:a)
==> NIL
(equalp '#:a '#:a)
==> NIL
(string= '#:a '#:a)
==> T
```

Comment: Take away rules of thumb?

1. When comparing numbers (of any type) always use `=` (unless you are comparing the representation of the numbers).

2. Two objects are `equal` iff their printed representations are the same (unless the objects are symbols, hash tables, structures, or nonstring arrays).

3. You can use `string=` to compare symbol names as well as strings.

Comment: @davypough: precisely. except in <3> i would say _use `string=` to compare `symbol`s as well as `string`s_.